# Show when clicked on any of <li> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I have a page with different `<li>` elements with content under them. The content is hidden, and it is meant to be that when you click on the `<li>` element, the content under it, which is hidden, slides down and becomes shown. I have tried different methods, but none currently have worked as intended.

Here is a JSFiddle where only the first element works, but I need it for all elements, and, if possible, then with a slide effect. Thank you.

**[Link To fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmLvs1za/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li id="virsraksts" class="slid">
    <h3>{{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}: {{ post.title }}</h3>
  </li>
  <div id="kontents" class="storijs">
    <div style="height:20px;"></div>
    {{ post.content }}
    <div style="height:20px;"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.storijs {
  display: none;
}

.para {
  display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("virsraksts").onclick = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("kontents").classList.toggle("para");
}
```

Comment: you can't have duplicate Ids

Comment: go with classes

Comment: You mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/mmLvs1za/3/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few Issues in your code:

1) You have used duplicate IDs. IDs must be unique. getElementById only selects first element with that ID.

2) You have added div as child element in `ul`. which makes the markup invalid. You should rather put that div element in li.

```
<li id="virsraksts" class="slid">
 <h3>{{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}: {{ post.title }}</h3>
</li>
<li class="storijs"><div id="kontents">
 <div style="height:20px;"></div>
  {{ post.content }}
 <div style="height:20px;"></div>
 </div>
 </li>
```

**Solution:**

Use classname(`slid`) to target these elements as they have common class. and to target relevant `.kontents` element, traverse using `.next()` selector as its immediate next sibling of `.slid`:

```
$('.slid').click(function(){
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hcdnm2g2/)**

Comment: Would not be better if the event was bound like: `$('ul').on('click', 'li.slid', function() {... ` in case of dynamic posts ? Not sure if it's the case anyway..

Comment: Yes, Only when the elements are added dynamically. However OP haven't shared anything pertaining to that. hence i have stated static event binding.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I needed! Edited it a bit and worked like a charm.   https://jsfiddle.net/hcdnm2g2/1/

Answer (score -1):

Id is unique attribute and can be assigned to one element only. Every time you will try to `getElementById` it will get first LI only. Try using Class.

Answer (score -1):

In your html code you have use ID in `<li>` tag. ID should be unique. If you use different id name it will be work